# Can programs which are written in C++ run anywhere?

Tags: c++

I know that for running C++ on Windows you need to compile specifically for Windows and the same goes for Linux and on...

But for example, if I'm compiling a program for Windows written in native C++, can I run it on a freshly-installed Windows PC? I mean, without downloading [Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) runtime libraries, etc., can I just compile it, let's say, reinstall Windows on my computer, and run it without installing anything else?

(The question above is using Windows as an example, but can the same thing be done on freshly-installed Linux distribution? E.g., [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).)

Comment: The operating system is written in C or C++ so the libraries are usually preinstalled.

Comment: When they're building the operation system they're using c++'s STD or c standard library?

Comment: It depends on the run-time libraries your program uses

Comment: I meant using only c++'s STD or c's standard library

Comment: Well, there are plenty of standard libraries.

Comment: It also matters *which version* of *which compiler* with *which compilation options* is used.

Comment: You have to link the standard library statically. Otherwise it will only work if the version of the standard library for your compiler is installed in your OS by default (which you can't rely on, in general).

Comment: @Alex and on GNU/Linux, linking against standard library statically may make things worse than just relying on *reasonably fresh* glibc being there.

Comment: Create installers/packages (.MSI for windows, .rpm, .deb etc for Linux, likewise for MacOS) and bundle all your dependencies in the installation package.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The only answer is "it depends".

There are many ways that an OS can "run" a program, many ways a program can be build, and many ways code can be assembled.

A program that uses only "standard libraries" and that **links all libraries statically**, does not need any other dependency (in the sense that all the code it need is in the binary itself or into OS libraries that -being part of the system itself- are already on the system).

But:

- statically link the standard libraries (which are most likely present in all programs) will bloat the memory usage of many copy of the same code. That's the reason library are often linked dynamically, but this requires "installation" of those libraries as well
- Programs that use only standard libraries can do only the things that are somehow "common" (or can be commonly represented) into all systems, thus losing all the peculiarity that makes an OS different from another.
- There are "platforms" that - by the nature of their peripherals - are not represented one into the other: a coffee machine has 12 keys and a textual 2 row x 20 col display. A PC has a mouse, a keyboard, and a display that can reach even 10'000 pixels of width, of millions of color each. A tablet has a touch surface that can seize multiple points at the same time.
  Can you imagine a program running the same on all those three platform?

Answer (score 3):

No. Often the libraries are different on different systems. If your program involves any GUI then you will definitely have OS specific code that won't run on other OSes.

If you write a C++ program targeting the [g++](https://www.cprogramming.com/g++.html) compiler without GUI code there may still be some OS-specific code. But you should be able to port it with minimal effort.

If your program only uses [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) and stdio, then it will probably be portable. For example, MS STL's ::c_str() function works a little different than the Linux one.

Comment: I meant if I'm building program using only c++'s STD library or only c's standard library.

Comment: But do i need to make any changes to the source code if I'm using std::c_str before I'm compiling for windows after building the program for linux?

Comment: Not as long as you don't rely on zero-indexing and instead call the string length function. You shouldn't have any portability concerns unless you are writing a long and complicated program.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, when using [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) with static linkage to [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) and [libc++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library#Implementations), it's very likely that your C++ application will work on any Windows system [Windows 95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95) and later, unless you specifically enabled functionality in the Windows API that isn't available, like [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) features. All of my [SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) applications compiled for Windows 7 (compiled in 32 bit of course) work fine on my Windows 95 machine.

When deploying a Linux application, it's best to just supply the source plus a configure script or makefile. This will ensure that the user has valid dependencies for your application. You could deploy binaries to specific package managers if you wanted to though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the standard libraries are everywhere. Just think about it, most of your programs that you get are written in C/C++. Only dependencies come when you use some specified libraries, like [Winsock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock), etc. Therefore some Windows applications are unlikely to work on Linux and vice versa.

Comment: Yea but i meant using only c++'s STD or c's standard library

Comment: @UnTraDe Yes, the default install for pretty much any consumer OS will include an implementation of the C and C++ standard libraries.

Comment: Well, standard input and output are the same. For an instance when it comes to reading from files, assembly code is basically the same, only interupt vectors are different, so compiling with different target OS selected would work.

Comment: @bames53 that doesn't mean a program compiled with VS2010 is going to run on a fresh Windows XP. The VS2010 runtime (which is, in fact, the C and C++ runtime libraries) is different from VS2008's runtime, which is different from VS2005's runtime and so on. This answer is **wrong**.

Comment: An executable for an Intel x86 processor running windows will not run on a Mac or on a Windows machine with a different processor (unless that processor can translate x86 instructions).  Executables generally contain processor specific instructions.

Comment: @Alex Yep, you're right. A brain hiccup on my part. Microsoft is a bit of an extreme case though; most c++ standard library implementations work much harder to maintain ABI compatibility across versions so you don't generally have the same problem as you do with Microsoft.

Comment: @bames53, about maintaining a "single C/C++ runtime": Microsoft did try, for years. Real hard. [They had to give up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx). It proved to be absolutely untenable.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Other operating systems manage it. And note that Raymond is discussing problems due to trying to maintain ABI compatibility for programs that do illegal things with private internals, not just the reasonable level of ABI compatibility for public interfaces that's normally maintained.

Comment: @bames53, You might find interesting to follow the "caused one application to crash" link to a related article and read up the heated back-and-forth in the comments over that very point of view. The reality is that Microsoft doesn't ship a single run-time because they have a duty to their customers to deliver to them a working product that solves their problems. A single C run-time had become a hindrance to solving their customer's problems.

Comment: @EuroMicelli The fact remains that other operating systems manage okay. Also Microsoft has been making some changes back in the direction of having the library as an OS component with their Universal CRT.