# How to use iostream in VxWorks?

Tags: iostream, vxworks

I am developing programs for VxWorks using Tornado 2.2. I meet some problem when I try to use **cout**. My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << "Hi" << endl;
}
```

The project can be compiled without error. But when I try to download the **.out** file to the target machine (mounted on VMware), I got the following error:

[image: error]

What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this target machine have a compatible C++ Standard Library installed? i.e. (A) any stdlib at all, (B) of a compatible version, and (C) compatible with the name mangling used by the compiler you used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can programs which are written in c++ run anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694719/can-programs-which-are-written-in-c-run-anywhere)

Comment: Do you know how to check the requirement you mentioned above in my target machine?

Comment: No, because you didn't tell us anything about that target machine. It's up to you to know how to check/install software on your systems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are missing the appropriate library in the kernel configuration. To rectify this, you will need to add the correct component to the kernel configuration.

At the least, you will need to add INCLUDE_CPLUS_IOSTREAMS, however this might also require other components, possibly one or more of INCLUDE_CPLUS, INCLUDE_CPLUS_DEMANGLER or INCLUDE_CPLUS_LANG, dependant on what is already included.

If you are using the tornado GUI to configure your kernel, you can just browse through the tree - I can't remember the exact location in Tornado, but is fairly near the top - probably under C++ Components.

If you are using the command line to make your project, you may need to edit config.h directly.

Comment: I tried adding those macros in config.h, but it didn't work and the problem still exists. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765475/how-to-configure-the-bootrom-parameters-for-vxworks-5-5)'s another problem that I came across. It seems that some parameters in config.h are ignored or overwritten during the boot. These confuse me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

That's some old tech you got there... Check you kernel configuration for various CPLUS options - you're missing something.

Comment: How to check my kernel configuration?

Comment: Depends on how you're building it: from Tornado GUI or command line make. The GUI has a configuration tool. Make requires editing config.h (using configAll.h as a guide). I think you need to define INCLUDE_CPLUS_IOSTREAMS.