# How to configure the bootrom parameters for VxWorks 5.5?

Tags: vxworks

I have a problem configuring the bootrom parameters for my virtual machine VxWorks 5.5.

I want to change the target IP address. I tried modifying the DEFAULT_BOOT_LINE macro in *config.h*. But, I didn't work. I use *printf* to check the value of DEFAULT_BOOT_LINE. It didn't changed.

This seems that DEFAULT_BOOT_LINE is defined elsewhere beside *config.h* and can't be modified. Do you know what the problem is? Is there other methods to change the bootrom parameters?

Comment: DEFAULT_BOOT_LINE is only used if you have not modified earlier bootparams, as its stored in NVRAM. So if you have changed it, older values will be picked up. As a test you can clear NVRAM and then it DEFAULT_BOOT_LINE will be in effect.

Answer (score 0):

To erase BOOT_LINE_ADRS and get back to DEFAULT_BOOT_LINE,

```
-> my_boot_line = malloc (8)
-> memset my_boot_line, 0x00, 8
-> memset my_boot_line, 0xff, 4
-> sysNvRamSet my_boot_line, 8, 0 /* This line depends on your BSP. */
```

To change boot parameters at the bootrom prompt,

```
[VxWorks Boot] c
```

To change boot parameters at shell prompt,

```
-> bootChange /* at the shell prompt */
```